# c# - Search for UPnP Devices like Intel UPnP Spy

Tags: c#, networking, upnp

I've googled this topic up and down for a couple hours and found nothing... er... less than nothing...

I need a simple C# script to code a UPnP Spy like the Intel Device Spy... I cannot use the intel app because in our company we're providing power meters with network abilities which are mounted as upnp devices. Some of our customers weren't able to find these devices in our own app... so now we need a sipmle to understand Device Spy where our customers can see the ip adress of the upnp device... If anyone has got something like this already... it would be nice2have :D

big thanks
best regards
blacktronix

Answer (score 1):

Intel has a whole .NET 'SDK' for UPnP.

Why dont you just use that?

On another note, many hardware manufacturers does not implement it correctly, and hence can fail.  I had to write my own implementation for a router I have. It is not so hard to do.

Comment: do you realize that intels open source upnp SDK has 0 documentation? not one piece, not on the site, not on any other site. they provide you classes and expect you to figure out how to use them by guessing, which i wasn't able to do!

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder: the code is pretty self explanatory if you familiarize yourself with the uPnP spec (which in itself is quite trivial).

Comment: did you try to decipher the usage from the classes? it isn't structured in a logical, easy to dephicer manner, as i have tried to figure out the usage. ie: microsofts one is simple, but intels is not as easy to decipher using no documentation as microsofts is, if you've had any luck, documenting (say) getting a list of devices would be a great help, preferably synchronously rather than async.

Comment: Unfortunately we are talking about 6-7 years ago. I dont remember details that far back.